# Android MediaRecorder: Difference between AmrWb and ThreeGpp OutputFormat

Tags: android, mediarecorder, google-cloud-speech, audioformat

If i use the Android MediaRecorder to record i file i can set its properties like this:

```
this.recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
this.recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.AmrWb);
this.recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AmrWb);
this.recorder.SetAudioSamplingRate(16000);
```

It generates a **3gpp**-File. If i send the recorded file to the Google Cloud Speech API the audio is recognized and transformed into text:

```
var response = speech.SyncRecognize(new RecognitionConfig()
            {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.AmrWb,
                SampleRate = 16000,
                LanguageCode ="de-DE"
            }, RecognitionAudio.FromFile("test.3gpp"));
```

However, if i change the OutputFormat to

```
this.recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.ThreeGpp);
```

it also generates a .3gpp-File, but the Google Cloud API throws an error. That's strange, because i thought the OutputFormat doesn't matter and just defines the container of the encoded data which are AMR encoded in both cases. So my question is:

**What exactly is the difference between the AMR and the ThreeGpp OutputFormat?**

Comment: Usually 3GPP is video container holds both AudioStream ( Can be AMR/AAC..) and VideoStream (Can be MP4)

Comment: So its a container or a format? What is the difference between a "container" and a "audio format"? I always thought an audio file consists of a container (defining the file extension) containing header informations and one or multiple decoded audio data, using a specific codec.

also so i'm wondering why the 3gpp container format does not work with the google cloud speech api.